# Assignment aand Precedence of operators in c

Tags: javascript, html, c, variables, micr

somebody explain this please
don't anyy me with ridiculous code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int a = 5 ;
    printf( "%d %d %d %d %d", a, ++a, a++,--a,a--);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and ask an actual question.

Comment: please edit your question and make it clear.

Comment: It's ridiculous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which the arguments of printf are evaluated is implementation specific. Output change from machine to machine.